# How to get out of edit mode in CircuitMaker?

Tags: pcb, circuitmaker

When I edit a PCB in CircuitMaker, I start laying out tracks on both upper and bottom layer.
So far so good. Sometimes, I want to stop, and press `Escape`. Mostly this works, sometimes, I have to press twice, or three times.

When selecting an item, sometimes trace mode is still enabled, sometimes not.

But I had already twice in a few hours, that I cannot get out of a mode that keeps creating tracks. I cannot get even out of the black screen (see below). I cannot reach the menu, the left pane, or the window below. It just keeps scrolling.

Actually, as I'm writing this (using Alt-Tab I had to change application), it is still scrolling, and it will do so until I with TaskManager kill the application and lose (again) some work.

How can I get out of edit mode when the Escape key does not work?

(If I keep getting problems with CircuitMaker, my next question might be: how to convert a CircuitMaker to KiCad?.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on an empty area. Right-clicking is a sort of way to exit either placing a trace, or the currently selected tool in both CircuitMaker and Altium Designer.

Comment: That doesn't work, it only switches between 'placing a via' mode and 'trace mode' ... scrolling keeps continuing when I want to get out of the PCB pane.

Edit: it seems to work sometimes (1 out of 10 times) ... I hope I find a real solution, because this really makes working with CircuitMaker unbelievably cumbersome.

Comment: It seems to work most of the time indeed, too bad my board is quite big and I have to scroll outside the edge to find an empty area (as the board itself is taken into account).

Comment: It's definitely not the most responsive interface. I use CircuitMaker at home and Altium Designer at work. The former definitely feels less responsive, but I think intentionally so.

Comment: Probably because it's internet based, if it would be a 'delay' it's just annoying, but (at least when I'm using it), it is not responding, so I have to click multiple times, and if I click once too often it starts an information window with results in some error etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Altium Designer it is the right mouse button, but I'm not sure about CircuitMaker. They switched around a lot of the basic controls for no well-explained reason. The Esc key is always my go-to for cases like this - it is mostly universal and doesn't require clicking on just the right area with the mouse pointer.

Comment: I will try, but I'm almost sure I tried this already (since indeed is intuitive).

Comment: At least if you hit it too many times it won't open up a new window. I often find myself hitting the escape key 3-5 times a go. Logically it's completely pointless to do this, but it minimizes the chance of a missed keystroke